# How to resolve the absolute path with <spring:url /> for relative URI

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a website index ..... `http://localhost/myContext/`
a REST index .................. `http://localhost/myContext/restController/`
and many REST pages ... `http://localhost/myContext/restController/*/*`

The REST controller uses relative paths, loading the contents dynamically depending on the URL.

When these pages are hit with a direct browser access, all the pages works fine and you can navigate freely.

---

Now I want to integrate the `restController/*/*` pages directly into the `/myContext/` index using AJAX. The contents are loaded into a DIV; *the browser's URL will never change*.

My browser hits the website index `/myContext/`
Then AJAX loads `/restController/`, which points to a JSP...

---

Inside the JSP: `<spring:url value="something">` returns directly `something` instead of the whole absolute path based on the controller's servletPath `/myContext/restController/something`

Since `<spring:url>` returns a relative path, the browser tries to hit `/myContext/something` - *404*

I did this previously for forms using `<form:form>` and it works great. The action is created relatively to the controller's servletPath.

**What is the most clean way to get an absolute path with `<spring:url>` (or other) from a relative URI?**

---

I tried using `${pageContext.request.requestURI}` but it includes the JSP filename (`/myContext/restController/something/ctrl.jsp`), filtering the filename won't work since I rely on the presence or not of the last dash to navigate.

I also tried including a `<form:form />` and recover the action using Javascript. It's very ugly but it works... Not a good solution tho.

---

The code from `<spring:url>` :

```
private String createUrl() throws JspException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) pageContext.getRequest();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) pageContext.getResponse();
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
        if (this.type == UrlType.CONTEXT_RELATIVE) {
            // add application context to url
            if (this.context == null) {
                url.append(request.getContextPath());
            }
            else {
                if (this.context.endsWith("/")) {
                    url.append(this.context.substring(0, this.context.length() - 1));
                }
                else {
                    url.append(this.context);
                }
            }
        }
        if (this.type != UrlType.RELATIVE && this.type != UrlType.ABSOLUTE && !this.value.startsWith("/")) {
            url.append("/");
        }
        url.append(replaceUriTemplateParams(this.value, this.params, this.templateParams));
        url.append(createQueryString(this.params, this.templateParams, (url.indexOf("?") == -1)));

        String urlStr = url.toString();
        if (this.type != UrlType.ABSOLUTE) {
            // Add the session identifier if needed
            // (Do not embed the session identifier in a remote link!)
            urlStr = response.encodeURL(urlStr);
        }

        // HTML and/or JavaScript escape, if demanded.
        urlStr = htmlEscape(urlStr);
        urlStr = this.javaScriptEscape ? JavaScriptUtils.javaScriptEscape(urlStr) : urlStr;

        return urlStr;
    }
```

Comment: if you are not forcing to use spring url then with el we can achive this by  <c:set var="baseURL" value="${fn:replace(pageContext.request.requestURL, pageContext.request.requestURI, pageContext.request.contextPath)}" />
.here baseurl will be absolute value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `<spring:url>`doesn't handle relative paths correctly for embedded JSP files.
I had to create my own tag to do this conversion.

**The TAG code is:**

```
<%@tag trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<%@attribute name="value"%>
<%@attribute name="var"%>
<%@attribute name="id"%>

<%
    // Fetch the original request_uri from the request and extract its absolute path
    String url_absolute;
    String requestUri = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
    if (requestUri == null)
        requestUri = (String) request.getRequestURI();

    int lastSlash = requestUri.lastIndexOf('/');
    if (lastSlash >= 0)
        url_absolute = requestUri.substring(0, lastSlash + 1);
    else
        url_absolute = "/"; // Should never happen

    // If a value is defined in the TAG, we add it to the path
    if (value != null)
        url_absolute += value;

    getJspContext().setAttribute("url_absolute", url_absolute);

    // If a var is defined in the TAG, we set its attribute in the request
    if (var != null)
        request.setAttribute(var, url_absolute);
%>

<c:if test="${not empty id}">
    <input type="hidden" id="${id}" value="${url_absolute}">
</c:if>

<c:if test="${empty var and empty id}">
    ${url_absolute}
</c:if>
```

*This code could be improved to handle the scope, context and escapes attributes.*